# Copy paste from a text box adds extra lines

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

So basically I have a button that takes the strings delimited by line breaks in one text box that then formats them a particular way and puts them in a different text box. Everything looks fine when I run the code, however, when I copy and paste the text from the second textbox to a different place, it adds a line break after everything that I took from the original box.

```
private void ToTableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder tableText = new StringBuilder();
        string[] lines = BasicTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
        TableTextBox.Clear();

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < columnsUpDown.Value; i++)
            {
                if (i == columnsUpDown.Value - 1)
                {
                    tableText.Append(lines[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    tableText.Append(lines[i] + " | ");
                }
            }

            tableText.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            for (int i = 0; i < columnsUpDown.Value; i++)
            {
                if (i == columnsUpDown.Value - 1)
                {
                    tableText.Append("--");
                }
                else
                {
                    tableText.Append("--|");
                }
            }

            int currentPos = Convert.ToInt32(columnsUpDown.Value);
            while (currentPos <= lines.Length)
            {
                tableText.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                for (int i = 0; i < columnsUpDown.Value; i++)
                {
                    if (i == columnsUpDown.Value - 1)
                    {
                        tableText.Append(lines[currentPos]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tableText.Append(lines[currentPos] + " | ");
                    }
                    currentPos++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        TableTextBox.Text = tableText.ToString();
    }
```

I thought maybe this be because the split doesn't remove the \n but I wasn't sure how to remove it afterwards. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just add `TableTextBox.Text = TableTextBox.Text.TrimEnd(Environment.Newline.ToCharArray());`

Comment: I added that line at the end but still have the same problem. It looks fine in my second textbox but when I paste it in somewhere else, the line breaks remain.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that trimming the lines[currentPos] would be the correct way...

tableText.Append(lines[currentPos].ToString().Trim());